# Kinect v2 mapping color coordinates to camera space

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to map coordinates from the color space to the camera space.
The code I am using is the following:

```
HRESULT ModelRecognizer::MapColorToCameraCoordinates(const std::vector<ColorSpacePoint>& colorsps, std::vector<CameraSpacePoint>& camerasps)
{
    //Access frame
    HRESULT hr = GetDepthFrame();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ICoordinateMapper* pMapper;
        hr = m_pKinectSensor->get_CoordinateMapper(&pMapper);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            CameraSpacePoint* cameraSpacePoints = new CameraSpacePoint[cColorWidth * cColorHeight];
            hr = pMapper->MapColorFrameToCameraSpace(nDepthWidth * nDepthHeight, depthImageBuffer, cColorWidth * cColorHeight, cameraSpacePoints);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                for (ColorSpacePoint colorsp : colorsps)
                {
                    long colorIndex = (long)(colorsp.Y * cColorWidth + colorsp.X);
                    CameraSpacePoint csp = cameraSpacePoints[colorIndex];
                    camerasps.push_back(csp);
                }
            }
            delete[] cameraSpacePoints;
        }
    }
    ReleaseDepthFrame();
    return hr;
}
```

I do not get any errors, however, the result seems to be rotated by 180 degrees and has an offset. Does anyone have suggestions what I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Just to give a bigger picture why I need this:

I am tracking colored tape pasted on a table from the color image using open cv. Then I create walls at the locations of the tape in a 3D mesh. Furthermore, I am using KinectFusion to generate a mesh of the other objects on the table. However, when I open both meshes in Meshlab the misalignment can clearly be seen. As I assume KinectFusion's mesh is created correctly in the CameraSpace and I create the mesh of the walls exactly at the CameraSpacePoints returned by the above function, I am pretty sure that the error lies in the CoordinateMapping procedure.

Images showing the misalignment can be found at https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhQU7.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZhKT.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out: For whatever reason the returned CameraSpacePoints were mirrored at the origin in X and Y, however not in Z. If anyone has an explanation for this I am still interested.

It works with the following code now:

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps coordinates from ColorSpace to CameraSpace
/// Expects that the Points in ColorSpace are mirrored at x (as Kinects returns it by default).
/// </summary>
HRESULT ModelRecognizer::MapColorToCameraCoordinates(const std::vector<ColorSpacePoint>& colorsps, std::vector<CameraSpacePoint>& camerasps)
{
    //Access frame
    HRESULT hr = GetDepthFrame();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ICoordinateMapper* pMapper;
        hr = m_pKinectSensor->get_CoordinateMapper(&pMapper);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            CameraSpacePoint* cameraSpacePoints = new CameraSpacePoint[cColorWidth * cColorHeight];
            hr = pMapper->MapColorFrameToCameraSpace(nDepthWidth * nDepthHeight, depthImageBuffer, cColorWidth * cColorHeight, cameraSpacePoints);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                for (ColorSpacePoint colorsp : colorsps)
                {
                    int colorX = static_cast<int>(colorsp.X + 0.5f);
                    int colorY = static_cast<int>(colorsp.Y + 0.5f);
                    long colorIndex = (long)(colorY * cColorWidth + colorX);
                    CameraSpacePoint csp = cameraSpacePoints[colorIndex];
                    camerasps.push_back(CameraSpacePoint{ -csp.X, -csp.Y, csp.Z });
                }
            }
            delete[] cameraSpacePoints;
        }
    }
    ReleaseDepthFrame();
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Worked it out. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx

As far as the sensor is concerned, X+ is to the left as it sees, Y+ is towards the sky, and Z+ is away from the sensor. So your coordinates may operate differently than this. For my purposes using openframeworks your correction aligns the X, Y and Z.

Comment: thank you for the clarification @NickDevereaux :) Still find it a bit strange that they decided to put  X+ is to the left ...